# About category theory and physics

Tags: mathematics, category-theory

Could the ideas of category theory be applied to Physics, maybe simplifying how algebraic topology and sheaf theory and other hard-to-explain subjects are used in physics?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do Category Theory and/or Quantum Logic add value in physics?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3759/)

Comment: I don't think this question is similar to the one mentioned ;I'm asking about SIMPLIFICATIONS of Physics using Category theory'

Comment: @user128932: Do you have a specific (if trivial) example in mind that you think could be extended into a more general framework?

Comment: John Baez is a mathematical physicist who has quite an interest in this. Go to his webpage and search "category" on his web pages http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/

Comment: Those 'arrow and object' math 'constructions' like a graph with the arrows like edges and the 'objects' like vertices; or a 'vertex' A with an arrow 'f' 'pointing towards B being 'like' f: A --> B , or a 'function' 'f' 'acting' on A to 'get' to B. Could this Category 'graph-like' theory and the concepts used 'in it' like monomorphisms and epimorphisms and pullback be used to 'categorize' certain 'events' in physics and simplify what happens 'in them' in 'accordance' with what happens to their representations within the category theory 'graph' representation?